# Can you use an embedding + CNN model for both text and image classification?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-processing, nlp, conv-neural-network

I have a `tensorflow` CNN model with an embedding layer for text classification as follows:

```
 model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen, weights=[embedding], trainable=False),
      Conv1D(128, 5, activation='relu'),
      GlobalMaxPooling1D(),
      Dense(10, activation='relu'),
      Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
```

My colleague is adamant that this is viable but I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696575/keras-cnn-add-text-as-additional-input-besides-image-to-cnn) stating it is not feasible. I understand CNN as an algorithm can be used for text and image inputs, but my understanding is that you can't use the **same** CNN model for text input and image input: text will use `Conv1D` and image, `Conv2D`.

The linked post mentions:

> 1. Process the image using a CNN model.
> 2. Process the text using another model ... By CNN I mean usually a 1D CNN that runs over the words in a sentence.
> 3. Merge the 2 latent spaces which tells information about the image and the
>    text.
> 4. Run last few Dense layers for classification.

If I'm on the right track, how I can go about building two sub models (one for text, another for image classification) and merge the latent spaces. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, the solution to this is to build two different models and concatenate their outputs prior to the Dense layers.

You can start by looking at this very good article(although there it's about MLP + CNN, the logic is still the same) : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/

Therefore, the solution mentioned there is indeed viable and the way to go.